# how to encrypt decrypt data between angular app and django app

Tags: encryption, cryptojs, pycrypto

We are having a scenario in which our angular app calls our backend APIs (developed using django rest framework). We are using Jwt for API authentication. We have one endpoint url which takes username and password (POST request) and authenticate the user using django backends. We have deployed both the application on APACHE HTTP Server and using SSL (Https) for encryption.

But we also want to encrypt the request payload (data sent to the django API). In current case encrypt the username and password from angular app and decrypt the corresponding data in django. For this, we are using CryptoJs in angular app and Pycrypto in Django. But we are unable to decrypt the data in django.

Here is the decrypt function code we are using on django app:

```
MODE = AES.MODE_CBC

key = 'k%eu6sy)h&vue#5yrpok#1)^1ya#l1t('

def decrypt(ciphertext,key, mode):
    encobj = AES.new('k%eu6sy)h&vue#5yrpok#1)^1ya#l1t(', AES.MODE_CBC)
    decrypted = encobj.decrypt(ciphertext)
    return decrypted.decode('utf-8')



ciphertext_user_name=request.data['username'].encode("utf8")
ciphertext_pwd=request.data['password'].encode("utf8")
usr = decrypt(ciphertext_user_name,key,MODE)
pwd = decrypt(ciphertext_pwd,key,MODE)
```

We are using CBC mode in CryptoJs as well.

Above code is just a sample code. Can somebody suggest, is this the right approach to go, or we should change the approach and do something else.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody suggest, is this the right approach to go

Why do you want to encrypting the payload separately (outside ssl)?

When it comes to credentials (username, password), if you encrypt in the browser, you need to have a key inside the script somewhere. That doesn't add anything to security, only increases the solution complexity.

You may use an asymmetric cipher (RSA, ECC) to encrypt data using server's public key. Oh, wait - HTTPS does that already for you.

Client side encryption may have its place where you don't want the server to access the data (e.g. secured messaging, password manager, ..), however for username and password the server needs to read and process the credentials anyway.

> But we are unable to decrypt the data in django.

Here we have no idea how do you encrypt data on the client side. You may try to edit your question and add the encryption code and error message

> or we should change the approach and do something else

Though there are definitely some issues in your code (I am unable to tell if it's all of them)

- ciphertext (encrypted data) are usually binary (having non-printable characters). That's why when passing as parameters, the data are usually encoded to printable common characters (hex, base64, ..). I see you directly decrypt the parameters, are you sure the data are not encoded / posted  correctly?
- I see you are not using any IV (initialization vector for CBC mode). I assume you library used will just use zero array IV. Using static / zero IV is VERY unsafe for CBC mode (or any mode generally). Are you sure the client doesn't include some sort of IV?
- CBC mode is malleable, you should apply some integrity check (with the integrity secret in the client script it doesn't add any value either)

This all is already done (and done well) using HTTPS, so so you are just trying to implement another layer of encryption with not really added value (and as well with apparent weaknesses). I believe common advice here is to lean on HTTPS with confidence

Comment: Thanks gusto2 for the clarification. We will go with the HTTPS only.